# Character controller get stuck

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game with Unity. For some reason the character controller gets stuck.

[Here is a video of that](https://streamable.com/dwmrgm)

This is the player controller code:

```
private CharacterController CharacterController;
public float Speed = 12;
private Vector3 Velocity;
private GameObject GroundCheck;
private bool IsGrounded;
public float CheckDistance = 0.4f;
public LayerMask GroundMask;
public float JumpHeight = 3;
public float Gravity = -9.81f;
private void Start()
{
    GroundCheck = GameObject.Find("GroundCheck");
    CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
private void Update()
{
    IsGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.transform.position, CheckDistance, GroundMask);
    float X = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Y = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
    float Z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 Move = transform.right * X + transform.forward * Z;
    CharacterController.Move(Move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Y == 1 && IsGrounded)
    {
        Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2 * Gravity);
    }
    if (IsGrounded && Velocity.y < 0)
    {
        Velocity.y = -2;
    }
    Velocity.y += Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    CharacterController.Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too, judging by the code we watched the same youtube tutorial. The problem here is that you (and that tutorial guy) are making two calls to the Move function inside the Update function, this can cause the jitter you show on the video among other unexpected behaviors. You should only call the Move function once in the Update function and everything will be fine. So you need to combine X, Y, and Z movement in a single Vector3:

```
private void Update()
{
    IsGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.transform.position, CheckDistance, GroundMask);
    float X = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Y = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
    float Z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    if (Y == 1 && IsGrounded)
    {
        Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2 * Gravity);
    }
    if (IsGrounded && Velocity.y < 0)
    {
        Velocity.y = -2;
    }
    Vector3 Move = transform.right * X * speed
        + transform.forward * Z * speed
        + transform.up * Velocity.y;
    CharacterController.Move(Move * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Note that now we are multiplying by the speed before, just the X and Z components, because we don't want the vertical velocity affected by the movement speed.

Although it should work now, there are a few details worth noting:

· You should name your variables in lower camel case: "move", not "Move".

· You don't really need a Vector3 for the vertical velocity, it could be just a float, since you are just using it for one axis. Note that you are reading Velocity.y, but never Velocity.x or Velocity.z. AFAIK this is because you copied the script from the mentioned Youtube tutorial, happened to me too until I realized.

· I don't really know why you are using "float Y = Input.GetAxis("Jump");" since the Jump key should not be an axis, if you run into problems try this instead:

```
private void Update()
{
    IsGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.transform.position, CheckDistance, GroundMask);

    if (IsGrounded && Velocity.y < 0)
    {
        Velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float X = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded)
    {
        Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * Gravity);
    }

    Vector3 Move = transform.right * X * speed
        + transform.forward * Z * speed
        + transform.up * Velocity.y;
    CharacterController.Move(Move * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it get stuck as in "It vibrates near the cube trying to climb up" or in "I can't move the character as soon as it touches the cube"?

My guess would be that your character tries to climb up the cube. The cube is approximately 2 meters high (at least if I can correctly get that from the video), your `step offset` is only 1, though.

Another thing to consider would be your character's `skin width`. From the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html):

> It’s good practice to keep your Skin Width at least **greater than 0.01** and **more than 10% of the Radius**.

But yours seems to have a good value.

If nothing helps, I would recommend actually going back to a `CharacterController` with a size of 2 meters. Citing the Unity Manual again:

> You can modify the Height and Radius to fit your Character’s mesh
> . It is recommended to always use **around 2 meters for a human-like character**.

One more thing: Start naming your variables after the C#-conventions, which would be [camelCase](https://techterms.com/definition/camelcase). For example, your `Velocity` would become `velocity`, your `GroundMask` would become `groundMask` etc.